# Передача данных на предыдущую страницу при использовании TabbedPage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Только начинаю изучать xamarin и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
У меня есть MainPage что определен как TabbedPage

```
MainPage = new TabbedMainPage();
```

В нем у меня есть три ContentPage, которые я обернул в NavigationPage

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage  Title="Events">
            <x:Arguments>
                <GfRating:EventsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
 
        <NavigationPage Title="Rating">
            <x:Arguments>
                <GfRating:RatingPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
 
        <NavigationPage Title="Settings">
            <x:Arguments>
                <GfRating:SettingsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
```

EventsPage служит для отображения списка ивентов, по кнопке можно добавить новый, перейдя на страницу EventParameterPage и введя его данные.
Собственно вопрос, как передать введенные данные из EventParameterPage в EventPage?
Много раз натыкался на следующее решение:

```
NavigationPage navPage = (NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage;
IReadOnlyList<Page> navStack = navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack;
MainPage homePage = navStack[navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1] as MainPage
```

Но мне оно не подходит, так как MainPage не обернут в NavigationPage, как это и рекомендуется делать в документации Майкрософт.

Comment: Подсказка: есть такой шаблон проектирования приложения - MVVM. Его часто используют для WPF и Xamarin. Почитайте про него, может и примеры найдете, и вопрос сам собой решится.